# How to retrieve value from xml parameter in web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am new to C# ASP.Net and am following the following guide to do logging https://blog.tallan.com/2017/07/18/log-management-with-log4net-and-microsoft-azure/

I am unsure how to retrieve value from xml attribute using Configuration Manager. The following is my web.config file and I would like to retrieve the following value and assign to the string variable in my .cs file. How do I go about it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[queueConnectionName]

Comment: The following code snippet does not work, Visual Studio is giving me error that queueConnectionName : The name 'queueConnectionName is not found in the current context'